# How do I force composer dump-autoload to start from scratch?

Tags: php, composer-php, autoload

What is the exact set of files that I should manually delete in order to make sure that a subsequent invocation of `composer dump-autoload` will behave EXACTLY as it would in a virgin freshly cloned composer project that was just `composer install`ed, but never previously `dump-autoload`ed?

I am trying to reproduce and debug a problem that occurs during `composer dump-autoload` command executed as part of a docker image build.

I want to avoid the slowness of actually running a docker build dozens of times during the iterative process of finding the solution.

Deleting the entire `vendor/` directory and redoing `composer install` every time is also suboptimal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It always runs from "scratch". But I guess that if you want to be extra sure, you can simply delete the previously generated files.

The created files are `vendor/autoload.php` and some on `vendor/composer`, so you could delete them manually before re-dumping the autoloader.

These are the contents of that directory fresh out of a `composer install --no-autoloader`:

```
└── vendor/
   └── composer/
      ├── semver/
      ├── xdebug-handler/
      ├── installed.json
      └── LICENSE
```

And these are its contents after running `composer dump-autoload`:

```
├── vendor/
│   └── composer/
│      ├── semver/
│      ├── xdebug-handler/
│      ├── autoload_classmap.php
│      ├── autoload_files.php
│      ├── autoload_namespaces.php
│      ├── autoload_psr4.php
│      ├── autoload_real.php
│      ├── autoload_static.php
│      ├── installed.json
│      └── LICENSE
└── autoload.php
```

So you basically need just to delete

- `vendor/autoload.php`
- `vendor/composer/autoload_*`
- `vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php`

And you can rerun `composer dump-autoload` from a pristine starting point.

Comment: Thanks! I may be wrong but it would seem that composer suppresses certain warnings (specifically that some classes are not PSR-4 compliant) when regeneration of the autoload files happens to be idempotent. I am not able to see those warnings again unless I delete the generated files.

Comment: Maybe you are right. Haven't seen evidence of that, but the above should allow you to generate the autoloader from scratch.